# How to change the value of a React text input using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, dom

`$("[id=creditCardNumber]").value = '1234 1234 1234 1234'`

The above code works if I execute it via the Chrome Developer Console.  But it does literally nothing if I execute it via a custom Chrome Extension.

`$("[id=purchaseButton]").click()` works on all the buttons on the page, via the extension or the console.  So why can't the extension change the `value` property?

I have ruled out the possibility of it being a load time issue, because no matter how long you wait for the page to load it doesn't affect anything.

I'm trying to automatically purchase a product the instant it's back in stock.  That's why I need to input my credit card number automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your website is fantastic!  I'm sure anyone else with problems they haven't had luck solving here on SO will also find your service immensely helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using jQuery with React to accomplish updating a value. If you could provide a larger code sample from your component, that would be helpful.

But, here is a quick code snippet on how you could update the value of an input field:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <input type="text" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value} />
  )
}
```

`value` would then hold the current value inputted into the text field.

Comment: The website is `target.com`, obviously I don't own the website so where would I copy and paste this code?  I am not familiar with React but it looks like I wouldn't be able to execute it as-is in the Chrome dev console.  It looks like I'd have to paste it into a React js file, right?